# Distinquishing ALT+F4 vs. Taskbar Close events

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I'd like to determine whether OnClose has been triggered via `ALT+F4` or via Choosing "Close Window" from the application's TaskBar icon. So far, all I can think of is testing like so:

```
void ...::OnClose() 
{
     if (::GetKeyState( VK_MENU ))
     {
          // Alt F4 triggered close
     }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Bonus points: Is there a way to handle the windows 7 taskbar close window menu item specifically?

Comment: You can listen for `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`/`VK_F4` and handle the event directly rather than letting `DefWindowProc` turn it into a standard Close event.

Comment: Why do you care? ...and remember, it is possible to close a window by pressing ALT+Space+C

Comment: I care for my own reasons. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WM_CLOSE is sent by task manager.
WM_SYSCOMMAND is sent with parameter SC_CLOSE when you press ALT_F4 or from the system menu of the task bar button.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `ALT+F4` hotkey with the [RegisterHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) API. Run the custom code, then close the window.

Comment: Do not use a global solution for a local problem.